# Check if current time is between 5pm on friday and 9am on monday

Tags: php, time

I am trying to get a section of a page to only appear after 5pm on a friday and shut off at 9am on a monday, every week. I know how to do this if i know the dates, but not sure how to do this otherwise.

At the moment I'm having to manually update my variables every week.

```
    $startDate = strtotime("08/02/2013 05:00PM"); 
    $endDate = strtotime("08/05/2013 09:00AM");

    if (time() > $startDate && time() < $endDate)    
    {
        // contents to display
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how to get the current weekday? How to get the current time of day? How to write an `if (... && ... && ...)`?

Comment: of course, that doesn't answer my question. How do i check if something is greater than Friday 5pm and less than Monday 9am. This is a learning website, if you are going to criticize, then please don't. thanks.

Comment: @TheApptracker It's a learning website by *trying* something and doing some research. By the way there are thousands questions about php/time on SO, have you searched for one that suits your needs ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check if its friday after 5PM, saturday or sunday or monday before 9AM.

```
if((date('N') == 5 && date('G') >= 17) || in_array(date('N'), array(6,7)) || (date('N') == 1 && date('G') < 9))
```

`date('N')` gives you the weekday (From 1 for monday to 7 for sunday), and `date('G')` Gives you the hour of the day.

Comment: This looks like a good solution, except date('G') >= 5 would need changing for date('G') >= 17 as this is 24 hour format.

Comment: Thanks, i tried this and it displayed, even though today, at this time it shouldn't PHPFIDDLE http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/7jq-261

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, the time on the server in PHPFIDDLE is 4hr behind

Comment: Your example and brief explanation tought me a lot.

Comment: Needs a closing bracket `in_array(date('N'), array(6,7)` `)` <<<<<< Good solution though

Answer (score 2):

check for the day using

```
$day = date('D');
$time = date('H');
$daysArray = array('Sat', 'Sun');
 if(($day == 'Fri' && $time >= '17') || in_array($day, $daysArray) || ($day == 'Mon' && $time <= '09'))
 {
   // Code to display page
 }
```